# how to get current postion name using google map api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have `google` `map` api  which is able to get the `current` user `location` in `latitude` and `longitude` but instead i want to get the `location name`.

for example my location is **bangalore => vidyaranyapura** i want to get `vidyaranyapura`

here is demo : https://jsfiddle.net/aoe4vf17/100/

**html:**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3478, -6.2597),
   zoom: 16,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   map: map
 });
 // Try HTML5 geolocation.
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     var pos = {
       lat: position.coords.latitude,
       lng: position.coords.longitude
     };
     console.log(position);
     infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
     infoWindow.setContent('<b>You are here.</b>');
     map.setCenter(pos);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: pos,
       map: map,
       title: String(pos.lat) + ", " + String(pos.lng),
     });
   }, function() {
     handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
   });
 } else {
   // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
   handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reverse geocoding for this purpose.
Here is a working example with a `latitude` and `longitude` provided to the Google API.

More information can be found here.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

function geocodeLatLng(lat, lng) {

  var latlng = {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng
  };

  geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (results[0]) {

        //This is yout formatted address
        window.alert(results[0].formatted_address);

      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });

}


geocodeLatLng(53.3478, -6.2597);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch data from this json:
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json
with the url parameters `?latlng=[latitude,longitude]&key=[your_gmap_api_key]`

Answer (score 0):

Make a use of this and make sure to run it on https domain.

```
function getlocation(){
        /* Chrome need SSL! */
        var is_chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() );
        var is_ssl    = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
        if( is_chrome && ! is_ssl ){
            return false;
        }
        /* HTML5 Geolocation */
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function( position ){ // success cb

                /* Current Coordinate */
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                var google_map_pos = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );

                /* Use Geocoder to get address */
                var google_maps_geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                google_maps_geocoder.geocode(
                    { 'latLng': google_map_pos },
                    function( results, status ) {
                        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0] ) {
                            console.log( results[0].formatted_address );
                            currentlocation = results[0].formatted_address;

                        }
                    }
                );
            },
            function(){ // fail cb
            }
        );
}
```