# why i'm unable retain the address returned by google map

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic3

i'm able to get the `address` from `google map`  but unable to retain the `address` in my `page`

**here is my code:**

```
  title:string;

  informationWindowTitle:string;

  address:string;        

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  geocodeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;


         var latlng = {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
          };

          geocoder.geocode({
            'location': latlng
          }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') { 
              if (results[0]) {

                //This is yout formatted address
                //window.alert(results[0].formatted_address);

                console.log(results[0].formatted_address);

                this.title = results[0].formatted_address;
                this.informationWindowTitle = results[0].formatted_address;  

                console.log(this.informationWindowTitle); 

                return  results[0].formatted_address;        

              } else {
                window.alert('No results found');
              }
            } else {
              window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
          });


        }

  loadMap(){


    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);





      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

     this.geocodeLatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude); 

     //  console.log(this.address);    

     this.addMarker(); 

     // this.title = this.address;//results[0].formatted_address;
     // this.informationWindowTitle = this.address;//results[0].formatted_address;        

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);    
    });

  }

 addInfoWindow(marker, content){

  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
  });

}

 addMarker(){     

          let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: this.map.getCenter()
          });

          let content = '<h4>Your Current Location!</h4><p>'+this.address+'</p>';                     

          this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);                                               

  }
```

**what i'm trying to do is EXCERPT**

```
  geocodeLatLng(lat, lng) {

       // this function returns address

    }
```

**initializtion  1. loadMap() 2. geocodeLatLng()**

```
      loadMap(){


        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

         this.geocodeLatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude); // sending co-ordinates to above function which returns the address 


         this.addMarker();  // then adding marker


        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);    
        });

      }
```

`please refer this for getting` address:[how to get current postion name using google map api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447631/how-to-get-current-postion-name-using-google-map-api)

when i assign these properties i'm not getting its values

```
        this.title = results[0].formatted_address;
        this.informationWindowTitle = results[0].formatted_address;
```

QUESTION WHY? but i'm able to get inside `function geocodeLatLng()`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `this.title` inside `function(results, status) {...}` is not the `title` you declared.

What you gotta do is that using arrow function

```
this.geocoder.geocode({
  'location': latlng
}, (results, status) => {
  if (status === 'OK') {
    if (results[0]) {

      //This is yout formatted address
      //window.alert(results[0].formatted_address);

      console.log('result[0]', results[0].formatted_address);
      this.title = results[0].formatted_address;
      this.informationWindowTitle = results[0].formatted_address;

      console.log(this.informationWindowTitle); 

      // add this to force Angular detect Changes
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

      return results[0].formatted_address;

    } else {
      window.alert('No results found');
    }
  } else {
    window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
  }
});
```

When I tested your code, Angular does not detect when the title updated, so I must force Angular to do it. This is the way to use ChangeDetectorRef.

```
Import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(..,public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){..}
```

hope this can help !

Comment: your `answer` seems to be `intelligent` .  i have one question where would i put the above `code`

Comment: Just import the `ChangeDetectorRef` and inject it in the `constructor`.
Then fix the codes inside your `geocodeLatLng(lat, lng)` function as I did

Answer (score 0):

Try adding callback and use arrow function for preserved this:

```
geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, (results, status) => {
 if (results[0]) {
   this.doSomething(results[0].formatted_address);
 } 
 else {
   window.alert('No results found');
 }...
```

And the callback function :

```
doSomething(formatted_address){
  this.title = formatted_address;
  this.informationWindowTitle = formatted_address;  
}
```