# i'm unable to get current location in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm not getting `google map` in `ionic 3` i'm using plain `javascript` so i think it is not displaying in my mobile.

**here is my code**

```
     geocodeLatLng(lat, lng) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;


         var latlng = {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
          };


      geocoder.geocode({
        'location': latlng
      }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[0]) {

            console.log(results[0].formatted_address);

          } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });

   }
```

here is demo online:  [how to get current postion name using google map api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447631/how-to-get-current-postion-name-using-google-map-api)

**i tried to convert it to ionic 3**

```
    import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';


loadMap(){


    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);


  // don't know further steps

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);             
    });

  }
```

Question i want to achieve same result as this with ionic 3:[how to get current postion name using google map api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447631/how-to-get-current-postion-name-using-google-map-api)

Comment: do you have included
`<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">` ?

Comment: yes i have included this in my `index.html`

Comment: have you import geolocation module in app.module.ts file ?

Comment: yes  ` import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'; providers:[Geolocation]`

Answer (score 0):

First install the google map library using this,

```
npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

Now go to node_modules and then @types and inside that googlemaps folder and add below line,

```
declare module 'googlemaps';
```

Then import google map module in your component file,

```
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { googlemaps } from 'googlemaps';

    export class HomePage {

      @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;

  map:any;
  latLng:any;
  mapOptions:any;

    constructor(private geolocation : Geolocation){ }

    ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.loadMap();
    }
      loadMap(){

        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

          this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

          console.log('latLng',this.latLng);

          this.mapOptions = {
            center: this.latLng,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }   

          this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);

        }, (err) => {
          alert('err '+err);
        });

      }
    }
```

Now add this code in your HTML file,

```
<div #map id="map"></div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Oh..What will happen when we'll update Ionic to a new version?  We need to delete the `node_modules` folder right. Is that mean each and every time do we need to update this manually? Oh :(